# How do I look up a value where the criteria is offset in excel with a Formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a formula where I can look up a value when one of the criteria is in the row below the lookup value?

I tried the following code:

```
=INDEX(B4:F14,MATCH(C3,A4:A14,0),MATCH(E2,B2:F2,0),offset(-1))
```

This is the Reference:

[image]

The formula will go in "E3" of this worksheet
[image]

Comment: `=INDEX(B4:F14,MATCH(C3,A4:A14,0)-1,MATCH(E2,B2:F2,0)) `

Comment: Too simple for @ScottCraner that he did not bother with the cell/range reference locks $.  But I see they were missing in the original as well.